# Mono | Overwrite | Crash

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, mono

I had recently some problems with mono, apache2 and ASP.NET on my Wheezy Hard-Float image.

If I open the page the first time it starts and displays normally. After editing the page and publishing it to the Raspberry Pi via Visual Studio FTP Publish Mono seems to crash itself.

What mono does (as I can see in `top`) is that it creates first two processes and than spawns one after another. In result the Apache returns a

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at ... Port 80
```

Killing the mono processes and restarting the apache resolves this issue but why does mono crash after overwriting the existing files?

Here's the VirtualHost Definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ...
  DocumentRoot /var/www/.../...

  MonoServerPath ... "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"

  MonoApplications ... "/:/var/www/.../..."
  <Location "/">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    MonoSetServerAlias ...
    SetHandler mono
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
  </Location>
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using WebForms because MVC3 or 4 provide more errors than WebForms do :c

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Layouts/Default.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="RPiWeb.Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="title" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" runat="server">Testseite</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">
  This site is brought to you by Raspberry Pi with mod_mono and Apache2.
</asp:Content>
```

If someone could tell me how I can use MVC3 or 4 instead of WebForms I would be really thankful.

In case anything is unclear feel free to ask because I don't really want to use PHP.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @christianstuder nope, I stopped looking at it.